What would be better tags for "What is Bitcoin?"
What is Bitcoin? is currently tagged with exchanges, which doesn't seem very fitting. What would be better tags for the question?

A while ago, a new tag introducing-bitcoin was created. It is aimed at collecting "questions about methods and resources used to present Bitcoin to a person without prior knowledge of Bitcoin."
I've tagged What is Bitcoin? with introducing-bitcoin which is a better fit than exchanges, although it is not a perfect match.
